# Wordpress update on microsoft server

Tags: php, wordpress, updates

I try to update the version of my wordpress from dashboard it after updating it  i'm not able to access dashboard from it, It is showing this error 
"Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_raise_memory_limit() in D:\Inetpub\pacificalarms\wp-admin\admin.php on line 143"
i don't know what is this anyone please help me to solve this my server is on microsoft

Answer (score 0):

This error should not occur if WordPress was correctly installed. Can you check that your installation has a file

```
D:\Inetpub\pacificalarms\wp-includes\functions.php
```

Then check that this file has a line

```
function wp_raise_memory_limit( $context = 'admin' ) {
```

This is line 5572 on my installation.

Anyway, I think your installation is damaged and you need to re-install WordPress.

Comment: will you please tell how to install again wordpress manually ? what old files needed if i want my old database don't get deleted with new installation

Comment: Go to Dashboard -> Updates, then click on button 'Re-install Now'. The reinstall does not delete the contents of the database.